# Jon Skeet's chat reputation suffers from integer overflow!

Tags: bug, reputation, chat

Jon Skeet's chat reputation suffers from integer overflow!

[image]

His rep should roughly be 861.6k (SO) +73.6k (Meta) +4.3k (SU) +3.1k (Programmers) +3k (SF) +1.5k (other) =947.1k.

So there is 71k missing, which is roughly his Meta rep.

However, Meta rep does count for Marc Gravell. He has 599.1k (SO) +80.4k (Meta) +5.7k (Christianity) +2.1k (Programmers) +1.1k (SU) +1k (Islam) +2k (others) =691.4k.

It seems that it doesn't count for users who haven't been in chat for a long time (>5 years). It doesn't count for BalusC, Hans Passant or VonC either, whom also haven't posted in a few thousand days. However, it does count for Martijn Pieters and Oded, who have been active recently.

Comment: In chat I think MSE rep is separate, in the Tavern for example I show as 2k odd so it ignores my network-wide rep so I guess the same applies the other way around.

Comment: @PeterJ Which is why I included the example of Marc Gravell. The meta rep counts for him.

Comment: Ahh yes missed that.

Comment: I think you got it the other way around. Marc's rep is abnormal to me, not Jon's.

Comment: @PhMgBr Why exactly? It shows 11.9k for you, which is 4.6k+3.7k+3k+404+274 ~ 11.9k, so it includes your 3k from Meta for you.

Comment: Why is there no [tag:jon-skeet] tag on meta?

Comment: This was just a quirk in the chat system. Jon's chat profile appeared to not have been synced recently, so I forced a manual refresh -- now his rep is at 948k. I believe chat syncs profiles less regularly when users aren't as active on chat.

Comment: @hichris123 Why not add that as an answer?